# How to find out who is connected with me on the network?

Tags: php, vb.net

I have a wi-fi in my home with a password and i want to know who is connected on it with ip address and the name of this device.
Can this do with php or vb.net ?

Comment: probably. good luck...

Comment: The info will be inside your router. You will need to get its IP address and then interrogate it. Usually this is done through a web page and scripting it won't be easy and will be different for each type of router and probably different between software versions. Much easier to do it manually.